# Monogame Effect World Translation Z and alpha in objects not visible behind

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0, monogame

I have an effect in each triangle and rectangle:

[image]

In the triangle class I have:

```
Effect.World = worldScaling * worldRotation * worldTranslation;
Effect.Alpha = Opacity;

triangle = new[]
{
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(X0, Y0, 0), EFill),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(X2, Y2, 0), EFill),
    new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(X1, Y1, 0), EFill),
};
```

where EFill is a solid Color.

In the Rectangle class the equivalent.

Now I set the example to the following:

```
background = new Quad(new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(1000, 1000), "Red", "White", 0, camera);
background.Opacity = 0.2f;
WindowPanel.Children.Add(background);

triangle = new Triangle(0, -50 + 90, 20, 0 + 90, -20, 0 + 90, "Black", "Red", 1);
triangle.Translation.X = 160;
triangle.Translation.Y = 160;
triangle.Translation.Z = -10;
triangle.Opacity = 0.5f;
WindowPanel.Children.Add(triangle0);
```

But I do not see the triangle when it is behind the rectangle. (If I exchange the Z to the rectangle, the triangle is like the image)

I am new in the '3D' Monogame environment and I read a lot of documentation that could be outdated about AlphaBlend, Depth, etc. and I do not know what exactly applies and what do not.

So the triangle and the rectangle have alpha but are like independent of each  other when rendered.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Following and advice from @CaitVonSith, I changed the drawn order, first draw the triangle and then the rectangle and it is working like expected

Case Rectangle Z = -10

[image: Rectangle Z = -10]

Case Triangle Z = -10

[image: Triangle Z = -10]

Also works on 3D rotations.